# Why does IntelliJ IDEA have the 'show baloon' functionality?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is this 'show balloon' link you can click on in the Event Log. Just why does it exists? Does the balloon ever contain more information than the log?

Just an illustration (the event here was a git checkout), the link is not 'more' or anything, just 'show balloon':

[image: git checkout balloon]

May not be the most critical question out there, but just curious.

Answer (score 0):

The Event Log tool window shows the information about "important" events that take place in IntelliJ IDEA.

The information about problematic situations (e.g. errors and exceptions) is displayed in red. In such cases, clicking the more link (if present) **opens a balloon with a more detailed description of the error or exception.** Clicking a description link (depending on the error, the text may be different e.g. NullPointerException) opens the IDE Fatal Errors dialog which lets you review the error and create a bug report.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/event-log.html

Comment: thanks, although this appears not just for errors but some other mundane events logged. I have added a little more detail

Comment: Its not just errors. There are other messages in blue. e.g. "The following plugins are ready to (blue) update (end blue)"